# How to enable realtime mode on linux?

Tags: linux, audio, real-time

I have sample, quite useless application, which generates signal(short spike of some frequency, followed with longer silence period, at the tail), then have to write it to sound card. Soundcard is just looped back in itself with minijack-minijack cable. So  my application records just transmitted signal, to detect latency of following path:

*app->driver->dac->lineout->linein->adc->driver->app*

First of all, for my task i require to minimize latency, to go beyound sub-millisecond range. 0.01-0.1ms will satisfy, as this is sonar application on PC platform.

And second, i would like to be able switch from filling whole buffer to work with individual sample. Or, at most to minimize buffer size to make it as short as possible. I've calculated need 16 samples or shorter at 192khz sampling rate. Perfectly is to work with individual samples in realtime, i heard this is possible.

So, how can i "enable realtime"? and what kind realtime should i need - hard or soft?

Comment: Note that Linux doesn't really allow hard realtime, even the "rt" version. You need a true realtime OS for hard realtime.

Answer (score 3):

Check your package manager for the "rt" version of your linux-image (kernel). Another option would be to recompile your kernel with the "rt" patch.

For a very good explanation about realtime kernel see this [link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Realtime_kernel) .

Answer (score 1):

> how can i "enable realtime"?

Csound offers 'real time' playback of audio via the command line. 

 http://csound.github.io/download.html

 http://www.csounds.com/manual/html/UsingRealTime.html

It requires you to download and install Csound, and use it in place of your default audio device.

> and what kind realtime should i need - hard or soft?

Csound is a 'soft' solution.